# Filling a matrix with specific pattern

Tags: c#, arrays, algorithm, matrix

So I have a matrix that is always the same dimensions and it's defined like this:

```
public void InitPositionsGrid()
    {
        int munberOfRows = 6;
        for(int i = 0; i < munberOfRows; i++)
        {
            if( i % 2 == 0)
            {
                GridPositions[i] = new int[15];
            }
            else
            {
                GridPositions[i] = new int[14];
            }
        }
    }
```

Now, I need a method (recursive or iterative - whatever) that is going to fill this matrix but with the specific pattern, so that it is uniform filling in all directions. The method is supposed to take 3 parameters, X and Y which define the starting position, and another one, number of places to be filled. Should look something like this:

```
public void FillGridMatrix(int startingRow, int startingColumn, int numberOfPlacesToFill)
{
    //Fill the matrix with the following algorithm but don't go out of bounds
}
```

Here is the picture showing an example of algorithm:

[image: Algorithm example]

The idea is: Start from the current starting place, check "above" two spaces (should be x-1,y-1 and x-1,y), check adjacent two spaces ( x,y-1 and x,y+1), and finally check "below" two spaces (x+1,y-1 and x+1,y). The coordinates might not be exactly those but this is the general idea. Note that when there is no more space "up" or "down" the places to fill should be on the left and right side equally. The starting row can never be the first nor last row. If the place that is currently being checked is already marked, skip that place. Max number of places to fill can be 87, as is the max number of elements in the matrix itself. After the first round, if there are more than 7 places to be filled, the algorithm starts from the top left, and ends with bottom right "adjacent" member from the starting position (2 and 7 in this example).

Any idea what's the best solution for this? C# is preferred.

Edit: Here is the solution that most closely resembles what I'm trying to achieve, the only problem being that this is not suitable for recursion, and it requires too much conditions for iterative solution.

```
public int PopulateMatrixAroundCertainPosition(int[][] matrix, int row, int column, int availableNumbers)
    {
        if(availableNumbers <= 0)
        {
            return 0;
        }
        matrix[row][column] = 1;
        availableNumbers = PopulateSingleMatrixPosition(matrix, row - 1, column - 1, availableNumbers - 1);
        availableNumbers = PopulateSingleMatrixPosition(matrix, row - 1, column, availableNumbers - 1);
        availableNumbers = PopulateSingleMatrixPosition(matrix, row, column - 1, availableNumbers - 1);
        availableNumbers = PopulateSingleMatrixPosition(matrix, row, column + 1, availableNumbers - 1);
        availableNumbers = PopulateSingleMatrixPosition(matrix, row + 1, column - 1, availableNumbers - 1);
        availableNumbers = PopulateSingleMatrixPosition(matrix, row + 1, column, availableNumbers - 1);
        return availableNumbers - 1;
    }

    public int PopulateSingleMatrixPosition(int[][] matrix, int row, int column, int availableNumbers)
    {
        if (availableNumbers <= 0)
        {
            return 0;
        }
        if(matrix[row][column] == 1)
        {
            return availableNumbers + 1;
        }
        matrix[row][column] = 1;
        return availableNumbers;
    }
```

Comment: Please attempt to solve it and come here with a specific question. It seems you understand the logic as you have written it out, so try to convert that to code. Otherwise it appears that you're asking the community to write your code for you, which is not what SO is about.

Answer (score 0):

No recursion is necessary.  Just keep on build on inner structure.  I created a little state machine to solve puzzle :

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace WindowsFormsApplication1
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        const int TOTAL_BUTTONS = 61;
        const int BUTTON_SIZE = 40;
        const int SPACE = 10;
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            BuildMatrix();
        }
        public enum LOCATION
        {
            TOP_ROW,
            LEFT_BUTTON,
            RIGHT_BUTTON,
            BOTTOM_ROW
        }

        List<List<Button>> matrix = new List<List<Button>>();
        int numberButtons = 0;
        public void BuildMatrix()
        {
            int centerX = 0;
            int centerY = 0;

            int loopCounter = 1; //count of number of loops around matrix  

            int numberRows = 0;
            int rowCount = 0;
            int columnCount = 0;
            centerX = this.Width / 2;
            centerY = this.Height / 2;

            LOCATION location = LOCATION.TOP_ROW;
            List<Button> newRow = new List<Button>();
            Button newButton = null;
            Button buttonLeft = null;
            for (int buttonCount = 0; buttonCount < TOTAL_BUTTONS; buttonCount++)
            {
                switch (location)
                {
                    case LOCATION.TOP_ROW :
                        if (columnCount == 0)
                        {
                            newRow = new List<Button>();
                            if (numberRows++ == 0)
                            {
                                matrix.Add(newRow);
                                newButton = AddButton(centerY - (BUTTON_SIZE / 2), centerX - (BUTTON_SIZE / 2));
                                //add first button
                                newRow.Add(newButton);
                                loopCounter++;
                                continue;
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                matrix.Insert(0, newRow);
                                Button buttonDownRight = matrix[1][columnCount];
                                newButton = AddButton(buttonDownRight.Top - SPACE - BUTTON_SIZE, buttonDownRight.Left - ((SPACE + BUTTON_SIZE) / 2));
                            }
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            buttonLeft = matrix[rowCount][columnCount - 1];
                            newButton = AddButton(buttonLeft.Top, buttonLeft.Left + SPACE + BUTTON_SIZE);
                        }
                        //put new button above button below, move up one row, move left half column
                        newRow.Add(newButton);

                        if (++columnCount == loopCounter)
                        {
                            location = LOCATION.LEFT_BUTTON;
                            rowCount++;
                        }
                        break;

                    case LOCATION.LEFT_BUTTON :
                        Button buttonRight = matrix[rowCount][0];
                        newButton = AddButton(buttonRight.Top, buttonRight.Left - SPACE - BUTTON_SIZE);
                        matrix[rowCount].Insert(0, newButton);
                        location = LOCATION.RIGHT_BUTTON;
                        break;

                    case LOCATION.RIGHT_BUTTON :
                        buttonLeft = matrix[rowCount][matrix[rowCount].Count - 1];
                        newButton = AddButton(buttonLeft.Top, buttonLeft.Left + SPACE + BUTTON_SIZE);
                        matrix[rowCount].Add(newButton);
                        rowCount++;
                        if (rowCount >= numberRows)
                        {
                            location = LOCATION.BOTTOM_ROW;
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            location = LOCATION.LEFT_BUTTON;
                        }
                        columnCount = 0;
                        break;

                    case LOCATION.BOTTOM_ROW :
                        if (columnCount == 0)
                        {
                            newRow = new List<Button>();
                            matrix.Add(newRow);
                            numberRows++;
                        }
                        Button buttonTopLeft = matrix[rowCount - 1][columnCount];
                        newButton = AddButton(buttonTopLeft.Top + SPACE + BUTTON_SIZE, buttonTopLeft.Left + ((SPACE + BUTTON_SIZE) / 2));
                        matrix[rowCount].Add(newButton);
                        if (++columnCount == loopCounter)
                        {
                            location = LOCATION.TOP_ROW;
                            columnCount = 0;
                            rowCount = 0;
                            loopCounter++;
                        }


                        break;

                }
            }

        }
        public Button AddButton(int top, int left)
        {
            Button newButton = new Button();
            newButton.Width = BUTTON_SIZE;
            newButton.Height = BUTTON_SIZE;
            newButton.Top = top ;
            newButton.Left = left;
            numberButtons++;
            newButton.Text = numberButtons.ToString();
            this.Controls.Add(newButton);

            return newButton;
        }
    }
}
```